# Does Memoization improve running time of this algorithm?

Tags: recursion, memoization, factorial

> "Given an array of n integers, return an array of their factorials."

Instead of the straight forward way of iterating through the array and finding factorial for each, I was thinking of a memoized approach, where I store previously calculated factorials and use them in subsequent ones.

For example: 7! can be calculated much fasted if the result 6! is stored somewhere. However, I noticed the run time of both algorithms is still O(n). (I might be wrong) Does that imply that we're not speeding up the process here? If so, does that mean that memoization is not useful in problems with non-tree recursion? (In Fibonacci, we effectively prune the recursion tree by memoizing the previously found values, in the case of factorial, we don't really have the tree, more like a recursion ladder)
Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I noticed the run time of both algorithms is still O(n).

O-Notation is hiding the most important characteristic here. It only considers the *length of the array* and not the **size** of the numbers which is much *much* more important when dealing with factorials.

You should implement memoization with a hashtable. If you do then you will get O(1) for each entry asymptotically.

Comment: I did have the hash table in mind. Actually just an array will do coz the number can itself serve as an index.

Answer (score 1):

In the case without memoization, the time complexity should be O(n^2) since you would need (i-1) multiplications to calculate factorial(i) without memoization.